# How can I use props in background-image with styled components in React

Tags: css, reactjs

```js
function Section ({title, subtitle, rightButton,  leftButton, background}) {
  return(
    <Wrap bgImage = {background}>
      <TitleText title = {title} subtitle = {subtitle} />
      <ButtonGroup rightButton = {rightButton} leftButton = {leftButton} />
    </Wrap>
  );
}

export default Section;
const Wrap = styled.div`
height: 100vh;
width: 100%;
background-image: ${(props) => `url("../images/${props.bgImage}")`};
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

This is my code but I keep getting this response:

> Property 'bgImage' does not exist on type 'ThemedStyledProps<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes, HTMLDivElement>, "key" | keyof HTMLAttributes> & { ...; }, any>'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you read and followed the styled-components typescript [documentation](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#using-custom-props)?

Comment: No I havent. I will check it out now thanks